# Apache Karaf Cave does not work with Fuse

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse, undertow

I have installed cave-repository to Fuse and afterwards I created a new repository. When I try to reach repository via http, I receive the following error from undertow.

NOTE: I did no change to undertow settings. It is a default fuse package.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010026: Async is not supported for
> this request, as not all filters or Servlets were marked as supporting
> async     at
> io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.startAsync(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:1023)
> at
> org.apache.karaf.cave.repository.service.maven.MavenServlet.doGet(MavenServlet.java:285)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)  at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> at
> org.ops4j.pax.web.service.undertow.internal.Context$1.lambda$wrap$0(Context.java:615)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
> at
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> at
> io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
> at
> io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
> at
> io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
> at
> io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I tried the same steps (installing and creating cave repository) in karaf with jetty, and everything works fine there.

During the search in google, I have found the following page in redhat but due to subscription I am not able to see the content.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4222431

Comment: You didn't write which Fuse version are you using. Looks like it's Fuse 7, which by default uses pax-web-undertow. Karaf Cave is tested for pax-web-jetty, which is default in community Karaf version. There's something probably with Undertow and async servlets - not specific to Fuse itself... Can you please create PAXWEB issue at https://ops4j1.jira.com/projects/PAXWEB with the above stack trace?

Comment: Yes, it is Fuse 7.5.0.

Unfortunately, I have no access to PAXWEB project to create a new issue.

Comment: I created https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB-1254 to track this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that (as I commented under https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB-1254) Cave's `MavenServlet` is registered using plain `HttpService.registerServlet()` without specifying *async supported* flag. It works with Jetty only by coincidence (doesn't work - as expected - with pax-web-tomcat and pax-web-undertow).

Karaf Cave should either use Pax Web specific `WebContainer` extension to `org.osgi.service.http.HttpService` or register the servlet using annotations.

We'll continue the discussion in Karaf/Cave project.